# Use customizer or sidebar for header settings?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, theme-customizer, options

I'm converting html into Wordpress theme. In the header I have a tel number and a button. Both are links, but styled differently.

Do you think it would be better to make them a sidebar (widget area) or as settings in customizer? What should be the principle choosing between customiser or widget area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customiser should not make a real difference in you decision as widgets are customized from the customizer as well.

In general widget areas (sidebars) should be used whenever the user has the option to put any kind of content in it. If the content has to be very specific you should start looking into specific options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planing to use a lot off different items at that are use widgets. But at your position I think using customiser will be better. I don't think you want to use other then phone number and a button is not big enough for a widget area :)